# sql error creating trigger in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers

I am using `sqlite 2.8.17` installed on `ubuntu lucid`  ( I used `apt-get install sqlite`)

I have a `college` table on which I tried to create a trigger(as mentioned in dbclass.org video)

```
create trigger R4
before insert on College
for each row
when exists (select * from College where cName = New.cName)
begin
  select raise(ignore);
end;
```

This causes an error

```
SQL error: near "select": syntax error
```

the schema for college  is

```
create table College(cName text, state text, enrollment int);
```

Comment: If you could put it as a reply,I could accept it..:)

Comment: If you insist :) I tried to find an authoritative reference for version 2 but, alas, no joy. I don't know what specific part of that trigger version 2 didn't like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That trigger works just fine with [SQLite3](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html). Perhaps version 2 doesn't support `when` or triggers or has a different syntax for the trigger body. I can't find an authoritative reference for version 2 so I'm guessing.